# What is an ideal way to return a status code or a complex object in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out how best to deal with the following scenario. I have a server that receives messages, processes them, and then sends responses back to a client. I want to have the `processing` step return detailed information about the results of processing performed and an object in some cases.

I have code like the following:

```
public void HandleMessage(Connection conn, Packet packet) {
    var somedata = packet.Read();
    var result = Process(somedata);

    if (result == typeof(Message))
        SendA(result);

    if (result == typeof(MyObject))
        SendB(result, extraInfo);
}

public [what goes here] Process(object data) {
    if (validated)
        return data;
    else
        return Message.Failed;
}
```

What I want to do is create a separation of responsibilities.

- Receiver : parses data into meaningful objects
- Processor : acts upon parsed data and returns a status code or object.
- Sender : interprets returned data from a processor(s), constructs a packet, and sends this to the client.

What kind of design should I try to implement to achieve something like this?

Comment: What does Process need to return? Is it either just a failure or data?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli It is either an enum or data. I'm using the enum to represent a standard message to send to the client that does not require data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using `typeof()` and lean more toward the `is` syntax:

```
if (result is Message)
```

My suggestion, is to wrap your object in a state, or skip the state result all together, and just return an interface from your `packet.Read()` method, and call interface methods directly:

```
public StateResult
{
     public StateResultEnum Result;
     public IDataObject Data;
}
```

IDataObject would be an interface which would expose methods which could vary depending on the data contained in it.

For example:

```
public interface IDataObject
{
    string GetData();
}

public Message : IDataObject
{
     public string Contents;

     public Message(string contents)
     {
         Contents = contents;
     }
     public string GetData()
     {
         //Convert the string to json
         return json;
     }
}

public MyObject : IDataObject
{
     public string Contents;
     public string ExtraInfo;

     public MyObject(string contents, string extraInfo)
     {
         Contents = contents;
         ExtraInfo = extraInfo;
     }
     public string GetData()
     {
         //Convert the string to json (And include extraInfo)
         return json;
     }
}
```

Bottom line: Avoid using `object`s anywhere. If your data can be validated, create an interface `IValidatable`, which exposes a method called `Validate()`. When you return `IValidatable` from your functions, it doesn't matter which object it is (Either of type `MyObject` or `Message`), they both provide means for validation, which is defined in your interface. So while you may not be able to do `obj.ExtraInfo` without some casting, you will be able to call `obj.Validate()`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for.